# How to run SELECT queries in PL/pgSQL IF statements

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, select, plpgsql

I am trying to run SELECT queries in PL/pgSQL IF statements using the code below:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    query_type   real;
    arr real[] := array[1];
BEGIN
    IF query_type = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster"
        WHERE ("Westminster".intersects = false AND "Westminster".area <= 100);
    ELSE IF query_type = 0 THEN 
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster";
    END IF;
END
$do$
```

However I get the following error, `ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function`.

Does anyone know how I can get the above code to work? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** This ended up working for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(query_type integer)
RETURNS SETOF "Westminster" LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
    IF query_type = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster"
        WHERE ("Westminster".intersects = false AND "Westminster".area <= 100);
    ELSIF query_type = 0 THEN 
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster";
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

I then called the function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(1);
```

Comment: A `do` block can not return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html)

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.

You can use `RETURN QUERY` only in a function returning `SETOF <type>` or `TABLE(...)`. Use the table `"Westminster"` as the resulting type, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(query_type int)
RETURNS SETOF "Westminster" LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
    IF query_type = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster"
        WHERE ("Westminster".intersects = false AND "Westminster".area <= 100);
    ELSIF query_type = 0 THEN 
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT "Westminster".*
        FROM "Westminster";
    END IF;
END;
$$;

-- exemplary use:

SELECT * FROM my_function(1);
```

Note the proper use of `ELSIF`.

Comment: So I created the above function and ran SELECT * FROM my_function(); The query successfully runs, however it only returns the headers and no row entries. I have run both the SELECT queries by the themselves and they return rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [`anonymous code blocks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html) support it. Try creating a function and defining its resultset to `table`, e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc() RETURNS TABLE (val INT) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To call your function you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc();
```

Note: keep in mind that the table declared on the function's header needs to have the same fields returned in the `RETURN QUERY` statement.